rails 8.0 upgrade remove redis dependency
We are planning to upgrade our application to Rails 8.0 and take advantage of the new Solid* features that allow us to remove the Redis dependency. I've done some searching and cannot find any upgrade guides that discuss the move away from Redis.
The application started out on Rails 7.0 and we've done the upgrades to 7.1 and 7.2 with some simple code changes. All we really needed to do was make some minor code changes to deal with deprecations.
What is the procedure for removing the Redis dependencies and replacing it with Solid*?

what kind of procedure are you expecting? install solid, deploy, delete redis.

I'm doubtful that it could be as simple as that if you are upgrading an application that is already in production and requires 24x7 uptime. Is there a need to migrate the redis data to solid? Would there be any impact on end users of the application?

cable and cache can just be switched over, nothing to migrate. for the queue you'll probably need to run your current job worker to finish any jobs in redis, any new jobs would go into solidqueue.
